# How to describe someone who mixes two dialects?

Tags: phrase-requests

While writing a comment today, I realized that I had used the British spelling of "analogue" while talking about my Californian accent. This caused me to wonder - is there a word or phrase for **someone who unconsciously mixes elements of two or more established dialects in their speech**, such as might happen to someone who's moved between different English-speaking regions?

By "dialect", I mean things such as **grammar, word choice, and spelling** - my pronunciation seems to still be mostly (but not wholly) American, so accent/pronunciation isn't as relevant to the situation I wish to convey.

I also specifically mean **varieties of the same language**. I'm familiar with the term "codeswitching", but as that's often used for what bilingual speakers do, it's not what I'm looking for.

Some examples of what I'd consider mixed dialect speech:

- Going to uni is hella important these days (California "hella" + non-US "uni")
- You've coloured the center wrong (US spelling of "center", UK spelling of "colour")
- Dude, that's a sweet as lunch, I wouldn't mind tasting it. Can? ("sweet as" and "can?", from different dialects, are both missing a few words compared to standard UK/US English. "dude" might also be a regionalism)

If there's a simple word or phrase that laypeople might understand, that would be ideal. But, if the best option is an unusual linguistics term or a complicated phrase, that would still work.

Comment: It's still called code switching. "Both in popular usage and in sociolinguistic study, the name code-switching is sometimes used to refer to switching among dialects, styles or registers"—[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code-switching)

Comment: I can indeed refer to it as code switching, but it would be useful to have a way to make it clear I mean dialects specifically without having to add a clarification like "[...] between US and NZ English".

Comment: *Dialogue* is a bad example because plenty of North Americans spell it that way. You should focus on things that can be heard in the real language, like grammar and word-choice, not on silent writing habits.

Answer (score 2):

A mid-Atlantic dialect.

> If you describe someone's accent as mid-Atlantic, you mean that it is a mixture of British and American accents.
>   For himself, he had cultivated a mid-Atlantic accent.
>   https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/mid-atlantic

Comment: I agree that 'mid-Atlantic dialect' might apply to the questioner's own case... but I don't think you could use it generally for a mixture of English language dialects (never mind dialects of other languages). You couldn't call someone from NZ who used Aussie phrases 'mid-Atlantic', surely?

Comment: @ArchContrarian I wonder if we could create a term *mid Tasman Sea dialect* for that particular case? I'm half joking but half serious as I think people would understand!

Comment: As it happens, it actually doesn't apply in my own case (US/NZ/Asian mix, in roughly that order, yet for some reason "the UK spelling" is still the common term). This answer does give a useful idea about what sort of phrases could be used or coined, even if it's less succinct/exact than I was thinking of. +1 for usefulness :). (I was also unaware that this meant east-west "mid", rather than a US speaker from Carolina!)

Comment: Yes, "mid-Atlantic" is a well-established and understood expression - in Britain.

Answer (score 0):

Someone who uses two dialects is actually called **bidialectal.**

> Definition of bidialectalism
>
> : facility in using two dialects of the same language; also : the teaching of Standard English to pupils who normally use a nonstandard dialect

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bidialectalism)

> 1985   Eng. World-wide 6 131   Until about thirty years ago Norfolk Islanders with few exceptions were bidialectal.
> 1985   Eng. World-wide 6 143   Islanders live in a bidialectal society.

[OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/18756?redirectedFrom=bidialectal#eid)

Comment: Found an article this ... http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/newstopics/howaboutthat/10051181/Ey-oop-one-can-switch-accents.html Quote: *Ey oop, one can switch accents Bidialectalism, where people speak with two distinct accents, is on the rise, according to research.*  It seems to be to be ability to switch from one to another as opposed to speaking in a mixed up version ?